# adjust text boxGrob

Tags: r, grid, gmisc

```
library(grid)
library(Gmisc)
grid.newpage()
gp <- gpar(fill = "lightgrey")
(total <- boxGrob("some text doesnt fit", 
                      x=0.55, y=.6, box_gp = gp,just = "center",width = 0.1,height = 0.1))
```

using the above code I want to reduce the text size to fit inside the box.
is there an easy way with cex or auto sizing call?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It seems that something is missing, `gp` is not found in your code.

Comment: that was a col parameter-now updated... I want to adjust text size if possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no autosizing call. What you need to specify is the `txt_gp` argument, e.g.:

```
grid.newpage()
gp <- gpar(fill = "lightgrey")
(total <- boxGrob("some text doesnt fit", 
                  x=0.55, y=.6, 
                  box_gp = gp,
                  just = "center",
                  width = 0.1,
                  height = 0.1,
                  txt_gp = gpar(fontsize = 5)))
```

You could experiment with calculating the width and adjusting it accordingly. Currently the width is calculated using:

```
txt_padding <- unit(4, "mm")
width <- grobWidth(txt) + txt_padding + txt_padding
```

Just experiment with different sizes and see if it is within your limits. The grobWidth is part of the `grid` package.